# How to update existing column using different df's column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have two DF's, DF A and DF B. Both have identical schema.
DF A's column C have a different value and DF B's column C have a different value, other data is exactly same. Now, If I want to combine both tables DF C, how to do it in spark? I tried to do join operation, but it is creating duplicate columns.
For example:
DF A:

`+---+----+
 |  k|   v|
 +---+----+
 |  1|    |
 |  2|bar1|
 +---+----+`

DF B:

`+---+----+
 |  k|   v|
 +---+----+
 |  1|foo1|
 |  2|    |
 +---+----+`

Expected result:

`+---+----+
|  k|   v|
+---+----+
|  1|foo1|
|  2|bar1|
+---+----+`

Answer (score 0):

```
df_C= df_B.union(df_A).where(col('v').isNotNull())
```

Take a union of two dataframes and remove the null entries.

Comment: I tried it, the answer is not as expected. I still see duplicate rows

Comment: Does your columns contains null, or empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `usingColumn` or `usingColumns` to avoid duplicates:

```
val dfA = Seq((1, Option.empty[String]), (2, Some("bar1"))).toDF("k", "v")
val dfB = Seq((1, Some("foo1")), (2, Option.empty[String])).toDF("k", "v")

dfA.withColumnRenamed("v", "_av")
  .join(dfB.withColumnRenamed("v", "_bv"), usingColumn = "k")
  .withColumn("v", coalesce($"_av", $"_bv"))
  .drop("_av", "_bv")
  .show()
```

Output:

```
+---+----+
|  k|   v|
+---+----+
|  1|foo1|
|  2|bar1|
+---+----+
```

Comment: I am getting a following error: NameError: name 'coalesce' is not defined.
I am guessing it is because I am trying to use it in pyspark and not in scala

Comment: It's available in pyspark as well as long as it is imported `from pyspark.sql.functions import *`

Comment: True, except coalesce expect one argument in pyspark and in scala syntax there are two

Comment: It can take any number of columns, see https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.3/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce

Not to be confused with this https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.3/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.coalesce

Comment: You are right I got confused between those two, thanks for the help

Comment: Still getting 2nd value of v blank:
`dfA.withColumnRenamed("v", "_av").join(dfB.withColumnRenamed("v", "_bv"),"k").withColumn("v", coalesce("_av", "_bv")).drop("_av", "_bv").show()
+---+----+
|  k|   v|
+---+----+
|  1|foo1|
|  2|     |
+---+----+
`

Comment: In your source tables, do you have blank strings instead of nulls?

Comment: dfA = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(1, "foo1"), (2, "")], ("k", "v"))

Comment: That's the issue as `coalesce` looks for the first non-null column. Either use `None` instead of "" or use some other logic to compare for "" instead of `null`